# WHat's the proper way to pluralize/singularlize my model in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.5.  I have this table

```
cindex=# \d currencies;
                                     Table "public.currencies"
   Column   |            Type             |                        Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('currencies_id_seq'::regclass)
 code       | character varying           |
 name       | character varying           |
 symbol     | character varying           |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "currencies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_currencies_on_code" UNIQUE, btree (code)
```

Then I have this file that should represent my table ...

```
localhost:cindex davea$ cat app/models/currency.rb
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

But when I attempt to look up a currency, I'm getting an error

```
localhost:cindex davea$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 4736
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.4)
2.4.0 :001 > Currency.find_by_code("USD")
NameError: uninitialized constant Currency
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

What am I missing?  Should the file in my "models" directory be defined in a different way?  I feel like the spelling is good where it needs to be.

**Edit:**Per request, here is db/scheme.rb file .

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170829205136) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_role_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "crypto_currencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "symbol"
    t.bigint   "latest_market_cap_in_usd"
    t.bigint   "latest_total_supply"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.index ["name", "symbol"], name: "index_crypto_currencies_on_name_and_symbol", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "crypto_index_currencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "crypto_currency_id"
    t.datetime "join_date",          default: -> { "now()" }, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                  null: false
    t.index ["crypto_currency_id"], name: "index_crypto_index_currencies_on_crypto_currency_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "crypto_index_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float    "value"
    t.datetime "index_date", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["index_date"], name: "index_crypto_index_values_on_index_date", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "crypto_prices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "crypto_currency_id"
    t.bigint   "market_cap_usd"
    t.bigint   "total_supply"
    t.datetime "last_updated"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.index ["crypto_currency_id", "last_updated"], name: "index_crypto_prices_on_crypto_currency_id_and_last_updated", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["crypto_currency_id"], name: "index_crypto_prices_on_crypto_currency_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "currencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "symbol"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["code"], name: "index_currencies_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "user_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "crypto_currency_id"
    t.integer "price",              null: false
    t.boolean "buy",                null: false
    t.index ["crypto_currency_id"], name: "index_user_notifications_on_crypto_currency_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id", "crypto_currency_id", "buy"], name: "uk_user_notifications", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_notifications_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.date     "oauth_expires"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "last_login"
  end

  add_foreign_key "assignments", "roles"
  add_foreign_key "assignments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "crypto_index_currencies", "crypto_currencies", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "crypto_prices", "crypto_currencies", on_delete: :cascade
end
```

Comment: Stop `spring` and try again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  What is "spring" in thsi context and how do I stop it?

Comment: *Spring* is a preloader used by Rails, you can read about it [here](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/README.md). In short, spring enables rails to start faster but sometimes it fails to load new files. To stop it run `spring stop` in console.

Comment: Can you put up your Schema file? `db/schema.rb`

Comment: @Gerry, running "spring stop" results in the error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `stop' for main:Object".

Comment: @nzajt, I have posted the contents of the db/scheme.rb file as an edit to my question.

Comment: My bad, i meant to run it in _terminal_: `$ spring stop`; then run `$ rails c` again.

Comment: Well I'll be damned -- that did it! No more uninitialized constant error.